# How do I update an array of strings within an array of objects using ObjectId in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, objectid

I am having trouble to understand how to update tags array within an object of arrays in mongoDB.

I have an array of objects and its corresponding ObjectID of which tags I would like to update on mongoDB. What I tried is to use a loop using updateOne specifying the ObjectID as a query to find the respective Document.

Something like this:

```
nodes.forEach(node => {
   const query = { '_id' : ObjectId(node.Id) }

   db.collection(collection).updateOne(
      query,
      { $set: { 'tags': value } },
      function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(result);
     });
  });
```

This did not work unfortunately. I have tried other approaches but I could not find anything that works

I have the following mongodb data structure:

```
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6022bc9f9b55276bd39f4e0"
},
"name": "TestProject",
"projectData": {
  "nodes": [
    {
      "data": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "6022bc959b559276bd39f4be"
        },
        "nodeData": {
          "tags": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "7022bc959b559276bd39f4ce"
        },
        "nodeData": {
          "tags": []
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "8022bc959b559276bd39f4de"
        },
        "nodeData": {
          "tags": []
        }
      }
    }
  ....
  ]
}
```

I would like to update only specific tags of objects which match the ones that I pass in as an ObjectID.
What would be the best approach to update a bunch of object values matching a specific ObjectID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, the filtered positional operator [$[<identifier>]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) identifies the array elements that match the `arrayFilters` conditions for an update operation.

- If you are updating same tags in each node id than try `$in` condition other wise you can use `bulkWrite()` operation.

```
let value = ["tag1", "tag2"];
let nodes = [
  ObjectId("6022bc959b559276bd39f4be"),
  ObjectId("7022bc959b559276bd39f4ce")
];

db.collection(collection).updateOne(
  {},
  { $set: { "projectData.nodes.$[d].data.nodeData.tags": value } },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "d.data._id": { $in: nodes } }
    ]
  }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ofPeMhXkxxz)

Comment: The tag content can be different per node, how would I do this in a bulkWrite operation?

Comment: Thanks! I tried this solution, and it works fine!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, I want to add my own solution to this.
Based on accepted answer, I build the following operation, since each node might have different tags and I wanted to be able to add to the tags each time:

```
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

nodes.forEach(node => {
  updateOneObjectWithTags(db, node._id, "projectData.nodes.$[d].data.nodeData.tags", node.nodeData.tags, "d.data._id", collection).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
  });
});


updateOneObjectWithTags: (db, objectId, updateKey, updateValue, arrayFilterKey, collection) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.collection(collection).updateOne(
    {},
    {
      $set: {
        [updateKey] : updateValue
      }
    },
    {
      arrayFilters: [
        {
          [arrayFilterKey]: new ObjectID(objectId)
        }
      ]
    })
    resolve(true);
  });
```